# What is the domain of a function of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Consider a random variable $X$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X}\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $X$ has range (or image) $\mathcal{I}\subset \mathcal{X}$.

Consider now a random function $f(X):=2X$.

What is the domain of $f(X)$? I believe that the domain of $f(X)$ should be $\mathcal{I}$. Correct? Or should I think about $f$ as a function of $\Omega$?

I am asking this simple question because I am struggling to find a source on basic random variable theory clearly distinguishing between range/codomain of random variables and consequent domain of functions of random variables.

Comment: Is there any reason to choose for $\mathcal X\subseteq\mathbb R$ as codomain? Everything works fine if you do it with $\mathbb R$ itself.

Comment: No specific reasons here. But if we are told that a random variable takes values in $[0,1]$ then I think it is reasonable to set $[0,1]$ as codomain.

Comment: Okay, it won't harm. Personally I would prefer $\mathbb R$ also in that situation. If you don't then you must adjust the codomain for $2X$ and make it $[0,2]$. In that sense $\mathbb R$ is more convenient. No adjustments are necessary then.

Comment: @drhab What if $X$ takes values in $[0,1]$ and it is a surjective map? Surjectivity looses its sense if you set set $\mathbb{R}$ as codomain, I believe.

Comment: Yes, but you can moderate the information like this: "$X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ in such a way that $[0,1]= X(\Omega)$". Personally I take codomains "large" and eventually give information over the image of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain of $f(X)$, or actually $f\circ X$ is $\Omega$.

It must be looked at it as the function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $$\omega\mapsto f(X(\omega))$$

Defined like that also $f(X)$ is a random variable if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a Borel-measurable function.

Comment: Thanks, regarding $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$: domain and codomain are set looking at $2x$ as a simple real-valued function?

Comment: Yes. In your question $f$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto2x$.